# Putting text on image with click of a button

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I want to add text from certain text fields to an image when i call an IBAction so that a new image is created with the text from the fields on certain places of the image. I don't even know where to start with this so i cant provide any code i have, sorry. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sounds to me like you should put a UILabel on top of your UIImageView.

Answer (score 0):

As MSU_Budog already mentioned, u just add a label at an imageView. Then you pass the imageView to this method:

```
- (UIImage *)getScreenShotFromView:(UIView*)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, YES, 0.0);
    [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

and save the image or replace the image in the imageView with the image or do whatever you want with the new image.

Comment: @maddy Maybe, but it is the most easiest way i can think of and he seems to be not that experienced.  Here   http://www.raywenderlich.com/50151/text-kit-tutorial is another way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can also try in this way, instead of adding a label to the view, re-draw the uiview with an image and with the text on the image.Later take the snapshot of the view:

```
- (void)drawTextOnViewWithFrame: (CGRect)frame
{
    //// General Declarations
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    //// Image Declarations
    UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed: @"your-image.png"];

    //// Rectangle Drawing
    UIBezierPath* rectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 510, 888)];
CGContextSaveGState(context);
[rectanglePath addClip];
[img drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height)];
CGContextRestoreGState(context);



    //// Text Drawing
CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(x,y,w,h);
{
    NSString* textContent = @"Hello, World!"; //Text to draw
    NSMutableParagraphStyle* textStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle.mutableCopy;
    textStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

    NSDictionary* textFontAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize: UIFont.labelFontSize], NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: textStyle};

    CGFloat textTextHeight = [textContent boundingRectWithSize: CGSizeMake(textRect.size.width, INFINITY)  options: NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes: textFontAttributes context: nil].size.height;
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextClipToRect(context, textRect);
    [textContent drawInRect: CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(textRect), CGRectGetMinY(textRect) + (CGRectGetHeight(textRect) - textTextHeight) / 2, CGRectGetWidth(textRect), textTextHeight) withAttributes: textFontAttributes];
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}

}
```