# Edit image in UIImageView and use new image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have an app where you enter information into some forms and press a button to email the image with the information from the forms put on the image. I turn the strings from the forms into UILabels and place those on the UIImageView and then I try to get that image and email it as an attachments. When I do press the button, I just get the original image in the email. Here's my code:

```
-(IBAction)emailToCustomer:(id)sender {
    UIImage *rebateImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rebate.png"];

    UIImageView *rebateImView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:rebateImage];

    UILabel *rebateLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    rebateLabel.text = productField.text;

    [rebateImView addSubview:rebateLabel];

    NSData *rebateData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(rebateImView.image);

    MFMailCOmposeViewController *mailVC = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
    [mailVC setMailComposeDelegate:self];

    if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
       [mailVC setSubject:@"Rebate"];
       [mailVC addAttachmentData:rebateData mimeType:@"image/png" filename:@"RebateCoupon.png"];
       [self presentViewController:mailVC animated:YES completion:nil]; 
    } else {
       NSLog(@"Can't Send Mail");
    }
}
```

All I get in the email is the original rebate image, even though I enter information in the fields. I want the text from productField to be put on the image from the UIImageView and attach the new image to the email.

Comment: You need to snapshot your imageview to get the image with the labels on it.

Comment: Why are you putting labels on an image view to add text to an image just for the purposes of email? None of that is needed. Create a new image from the original by drawing the text on it.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you place the labels on the image view, it will only return the image it contains.

If you want to have the image with labels on it, you need to snapshot the imageview, and attach it to the mail:

**Note**: You need to give the imageview frame, else the snapshot you get will not be of the image view.

```
- (UIImage*)captureView:(UIView *)view
{
    CGRect rect = [view frame];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```

You can then attach the image by:

```
    UIImage *img=[self captureView: rebateImView];
   NSData *rebateData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
```

**Another way:**  You need to re-draw the image with text you want. Refer the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34999721/putting-text-on-image-with-click-of-a-button/35000633#35000633)

Comment: I still end up with the image with no added text on it

Comment: I get a screen shot of the view itself, not the image view. I'm going to change the parameters on the captureView method and see how that works

Comment: Yes, you get eh sanpshot of the view with at the imageview place.

Comment: I changed bounds to frame. pls try again.

Comment: just so you know, I never put a uiimageview in the storyboard. I created the uiimageview object in the method and that's it

Comment: That is fine. The imageview need not be created in storyboard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101709/discussion-between-freefire-and-mr-t).